# Fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS keeps freezing on apt-get update - WiFi adapter problem?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, apt

I have just installed Linux Ubuntu 14.04.4 alongside a fresh install of  windows 10. I have checked the checksum of my ISO and that the Ubuntu USB contained no errors. But I am not able to update Ubuntu, nor use Linux for browsing for example. I continuously have (for me unexpected and random) freezes that eventually lead to a black screen. It seems that doing `sudo apt-get update`, just after a booting up the system, leads to freezes within a few seconds. But there are no errors messages visible and doing the apt-get update does not stop at the same package every time.

Is there any log that I could take a look at to shine some light on the problem or any other things to try? I am new to Ubuntu, so all suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:** I have taken a look at the logs in /var/logs, but it I can not find any errors in here. It seems that the system just freezes for no apparent reason. (the other OS is working fine)

**EDIT:** I am using a 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. chipset for my WiFi USB adapter and have no Ethernet connection. I think the issue is related, because the machine only freeze's when I try to browse the web, do a apt-get update, or try a new install of Ubuntu with updates on the fly. Also when I try to update and open Software via the menu, it freezes only if I am connected to WiFi.

Best wishes,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the wireless USB adapter was the problem The WiFi USB adapter was recognized and worked somewhat, I was able to make some connection to WiFi, but this always resulted in freezing the whole system without any errors messages. 
With another WiFi USB adapter that works properly out of the box with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (ethernet was not available for me), I was able to install the USB WiFI adapter (with a 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. chipset) by following the directions found on this previously asked question (http ://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adapter-installation). This solved the problem.

Best wishes, Ben

Answer (score 0):

The logs should be in /var/log/apt/

Open a terminal and see what logs are there.

```
ls -la /var/log/apt/
```

I have a history.log file and a term.log file. Take a look at them.

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
cat /var/log/apt/term.log
```

I think the one you want is probably `term.log`.

If the log is large and you are unable to scroll back to the beginning inside your terminal, then you can buffer it on the go and scroll up and down.

```
less /var/log/apt/term.log
```

On a side note, all log files are usually stored in `/var/log`. Maybe take a look at `dmesg`, `syslog` too.

```
cat /var/log/dmesg
cat /var/log/syslog
```

If you want to watch a log file "live", while your system is running, you can run it through tail and log updates will output to the terminal on the fly.

```
tail -f /var/log/dmesg
```

If you are using `tail` or `less`, you exit the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I have looked at most logs, but I can not find any errors. The last thing in the term log is stating the start of a transmission. Should I paste the logs in a link?

Comment: You can omit the `cat` when you use `less`: `less /var/log/apt/term.log`. And you missed the `apt/` folder in many of your commands. I'm editing that.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. The only one I take issue with is using less directly and not using pipe with cat. This is a preference, nothing wrong with using pipe I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on one of my laptops awhile back with limited space.  The logging directory is in /var/log/apt/ .  If is possible that you are filling the temporary space up or maxing out your memory.   Try and do an sudo apt-get clean and just try again.  If it continues I would do a sudo df -h and check the tmpfs to make sure you have some space available.

Comment: Seems tmpfs has lots of space before I start the apt-get update after a apt-get clean (1.4 M used out of 791M). Thanks for your sugestion. I will check out the logs.

Comment: How about the ram usage during the update?  Are you running out of swap space?

Comment: RAM is not full at all when I try to update. (i tested with free command)

Comment: I am using a 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. chipset for my WIFI USB adapter and have no ethernet connection. I think the issue is related, because the machine only freeze's when I try to browse the web, do a apt-get update, or try a new install of ubuntu with updates on the fly.